# Using JavasScript Onclick function to toggle visibility twice

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, toggle, hyperlink

My Code:

```
<div>
<a href="/forms/login-form.php" onclick="toggle_visibility('login-div'); return false;">Login</a>
    <div id="login-div">
        <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/forms/login-form.php');?>         
    </div>
<a href="/forms/signup-form.php" onclick="toggle_visibility('signup-div'); return false;">Sign up</a>
    <div id="signup-div">
        <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/forms/signup-form.php');?>            
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                function toggle_visibility(id) {
                        var e = document.getElementById(id);
                       if(e.style.display == 'block')
                          e.style.display = 'none';
                       else
                          e.style.display = 'block';
                }
            //-->
        </script>       
</div>
```

Problem: Only the LOGIN link works with the javaScript OnClick function and the Signup link does nothing. Although, when I removed the LOGIN link and its div, the SignUp works. Therefore it can only mean there is a problem with the way that I am using the JavaScript function.

Apparently I cant use the same javaScrit function twice. I tried adding another function with the same functionality only with a different name ie(toggle_visibility2) but I still only get the first LOGIN link working with the toggle.

If this is true, then how could I accomplish getting both links to toggle with JS

Comment: What you posted works just fine (except that you have to click twice because `display:block` is not set when page is open). There is something else wrong on your page. Here is the exact code you posted (with php tags stripped) http://plnkr.co/edit/vVJ0D99KoGPvpAiQrcjE?p=preview

Comment: actually, i have the display block set in my css so I dont have to click twice. To be more specific... I have a login link and a sign up link. One of which only exhibits the toggle (the login). when I click sign up (no matter how many times) nothing happens. i think this is because when JS is called to the page the LOGIN takes precedence and is used for the function. This leaves the SIGNUP out in the cold. How could I get both to work on the same page?

Comment: what browser do you use for testing ?

Comment: Your php includes are probably adding malformed HTML. Please post the generated HTML, as seen by the browser. Also, having display:block on your CSS shouldn't solve what @igorpan mentioned.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong place. From what you've posted your function and markup are **perfectly fine**. Only thing you could do to clean it up is remove `return false;` from `onclick` and add it to the bottom of your `toggle_visibility` function.

Comment: the code works fine without your included forms, check included files

Comment: -SmasherHell yeah i just tried an echo and it worked... Maybe i have to look more into what @igorpan was saying.

Comment: as for the page source @bfavaretto, the source code is too big to post by 1500 characters. Can I email you?

Comment: @user2218297 having display:block in a css stylesheet doesn't help you here. Where you use element.style.display in javascript it is looking for inline styles ie. <div style="display:block"> styles in stylesheets aren't taken into account here and this is what igorpan is referring to I believe. You can see this here http://jsfiddle.net/JTEvZ/ just remove the inline style and the alert returns nothing

Comment: ok i looked into the source code, and the problem is that the included signup form is not coming up. @TommyBs

<div id="hasJavaScript" style="display: none">
<form name="signup">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I included display none in my forms DIV:

```
<div id="hasJavaScript" style="display: none">
my form code....
</div>
```

The fix:

```
 <div id="hasJavaScript">
    my form code....
    </div>
```